# magento 2.4 programmatically assign simple products to grouped product

Tags: magento2.4, grouped-products, assign

I'm facing a weird error. I'm trying to create a grouped product with its own children. The children simple products have already been created so I only need to create the grouped product and assign some simple products to it. My code so far:

```
$product = $this->productInterfaceFactory->create();
$product->setData($data); // a bunch of basic data such as sku, type_id, price etc

$child = $item['product_links'][0];
     
$productLink = $this->productLinkInterface //Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductLinkInterface;
 ->setSku($data['sku'])
 ->setLinkType('associated')
 ->setLinkedProductSku($child['sku'])
 ->setLinkedProductType('simple')
 ->setPosition(0)
 ->getExtensionAttributes()->setQty(0)
;
$associated[] = $productLink;
$product->setProductLinks($associated);
$product = $this->productRepositoryInterface->save($product);
```

If I put `$product->setProductLinks($associated);` before the save, then the whole code throws an error like:

```
Call to undefined method Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductLinkExtension::getSku()
```

If I put the line after the save, the grouped product is created but without children.

How can I assign children to grouped product?